# React redux -- input field not letting me type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, input-field

So I have 3 input fields, one for name, email and password. The email and password input field are working fine, but the name input field is not letting me type anything. I have the values for the input fields set to come from user, so it auto-fills the fields. Here is my code

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';
    import {editUserData, fetchUserData, deleteProfile} from '../actions/index';

    const EditUser = props => {
        const [user, setUser] = useState({name: '', email: '', password: ''})
        const params = useParams();
        
        const editUser = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            props.editUserData(params, user);
        }

        const handleChanges = e => {
            e.persist();
            setUser({...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
        }

        useEffect(() => {
            props.fetchUserData(params, setUser);
        }, [])

        const deleteOnClick = () => {
            props.deleteProfile(params)
        }
        
            return (
                <>
                <form className='editUserForm' onSubmit={editUser}>
                    <h3>Edit Profile !</h3>
                    <div>Name</div>
                    <input className='editInput' type='text' name='name' value={`${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`} onChange={handleChanges} /> 
                    <div>Email</div>
                    <input className='editInput' type='text' name='email' value={user.email} onChange={handleChanges} />
                    <div>Password</div>
                    <input className='editInput' type='text' name='password' value={user.password} onChange={handleChanges} />
                    <button className='submitButton'>Submit</button>
                </form>
                <div className='deleteProfile'>
                    <button className='deleteProfileButton' onClick={deleteOnClick}>Delete Profile</button>
                </div>
                </>
            )
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            users: [], 
            user: {}, 
            registerSuccessMessage: '',
            user_stories: {}, 
            isLoading: false, 
            error: null 
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, {editUserData, fetchUserData, deleteProfile})(EditUser);
```

**Edit** (after the suggestion of @Boussadjra)

[image]

This is what state looks like after props.fetchUserData. -- where setUser is --
That is why I have input values to ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}

Comment: do you have some errors in the console?

Comment: The value of the name field is statically set to first + last name, yet those variables aren't affected by the onChange callback.

Comment: no errors in the console.

Should i just make a seperate onChange for the name field, maybe? @numbers1311407 
Thanks for the help

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do.  First name & last name in one field is always an error prone design (what if they're a "junior" or type their middle initial).  I don't know your requirements but I'd probably leave it as one "name" field (and perhaps try to parse the name later) or split it into multiple fields.

Comment: Yeah I may just make a first name and last name field seperately. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

`user.firstName` and `user.lastName` are undefined they are not defined as properties in your `user` state, so you should simply use the `firstName` and `lastName` properties as value :

```
 value={ us}
```

or define your state as follows :

```
 const [user, setUser] = useState({firstName:'',lastName:'', email: '', password: ''})
```

we suppose that the first and the last name are separated by space so when you come to update the state split that name :

```
  const handleChanges = e => {
        e.persist();
       if(e.target.name==='name'){
           let name=e.target.value.split(' ')
           setUser({...user, firstName:name[0],lastName:name[1]});
        }else{
        setUser({...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see what you did there. Unfortunately, it just copies the value or firstName/lastName and adds an a to the end. I'll post a picture at the end of my post so you see what I mean

Comment: Ah, I forgot to change the value. When I change the value though, the autofill messes up.  (I have user getting its data from props.fetchUserData -- a redux action --. That's why I have value set to ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the next state coming from the fetchUserData to better explain myself in the last comment.

Comment: i think that we should the object schema coming from props, i will update my answer

Comment: It's now doing the same thing as before (replicating the name and just adding an a to the end). I think it's just best I make two separate input fields for firstName and lastName

Comment: when do you have  this behavior exactly? first rendering or after typing something?

Comment: Once I type "a", the new name becomes "Nico Chikujia Chikujia" instead of just "Nico Chikujia"

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are setting the "name" `input`'s `value` to `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`, which are `undefined`. You could set your `user` state to initially have these properties, but I would suggest using separate `useState()`'s for each of `firstName`, `lastName`, `email`, and `password` (since combining first and last names in a single `input` is prone to errors, as mentioned in the comments):

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {editUserData, fetchUserData, deleteProfile} from '../actions/index';

const EditUser = props => {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const params = useParams();
    
    const editUser = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.editUserData(params, user);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchUserData(params, setUser);
    }, [])

    const deleteOnClick = () => {
        props.deleteProfile(params)
    }
    
        return (
            <>
            <form className='editUserForm' onSubmit={editUser}>
                <h3>Edit Profile !</h3>
                <div>First Name</div>
                <input className='editInput' type='text' name='firstName' value={firstName} onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)} />
                <div>Last Name</div>
                <input className='editInput' type='text' name='lastName' value={lastName} onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)} /> 
                <div>Email</div>
                <input className='editInput' type='text' name='email' value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                <div>Password</div>
                <input className='editInput' type='text' name='password' value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                <button className='submitButton'>Submit</button>
            </form>
            <div className='deleteProfile'>
                <button className='deleteProfileButton' onClick={deleteOnClick}>Delete Profile</button>
            </div>
            </>
        )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        users: [], 
        user: {}, 
        registerSuccessMessage: '',
        user_stories: {}, 
        isLoading: false, 
        error: null 
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {editUserData, fetchUserData, deleteProfile})(EditUser);
```